# A question about strong slopes (nonsmooth analysis)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization, gradient-flows

**Context.** I'm reading the manuscrip "Nonlinear Error Bounds via a Change of Function" by Dominique Azé and Jean-Noël Corvellec (J Optim Theory Appl 2016), and I'm having a hard time understanding a certain condition in their **Propositino 3.2**.

---

Let $X=(X,d)$ be a complete metric space with connected balls. Given a continuous function $f:X \to \mathbb R$ and a point $x \in X$, the *strong slope* of $f$ at $x$, denoted $|\partial|^- f(x)$, is defined by

$$
|\partial |^- f(x) := \limsup_{y \to x}\frac{(f(x)-f(y))_+}{d(x,y)}.
$$

Strong slopes are very important in analysing gradient-flows in general spaces (e.g metric spaces, manifolds, probability measure spaces, etc.).

> **Question.** What are sufficient conditions on $f$ to ensure that  $|\partial |^- f(x) = |\partial|^- (-f)(x)$ for all $x \in X$?

**N.B.** I'm fine with restricting the problem to the case where $X$ is a Banach space with topological dual $X^\star$ and $f$ is convex, in which case we have that if $x$ is not a minimum point of $f$, then

$$
|\partial|^- f(x) = \sup_{y \ne x}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{\|x-y\|} = \|\partial f(x)\|_\star = \{\|x^\star\|_\star \mid x^\star \in \partial f(x)\},
$$

where $\partial f(x) \subseteq X^\star$ is the subdifferential of $f$ at $x$. In particular, I have in mind functions of the form
$f(x) := \max \{\langle a_i,x\rangle \mid i=1,\ldots,n\}$,
for some bounded linear operators $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in X^\star$.